# Can scapy specify a source IP when used to simulate SYN / UDP flood attacks

Tags: security, intrusion-prevention

I would like to test an IDS in a test network.

I know scapy can be used to generate network traffic, in particluar to simulate fake SYN flood attacks etc like the one here [github](https://github.com/arthurnn/SynFlood/blob/master/synflood). All the example scripts using scapy show its possible to specify which destination IP to use, however they all appear to randomly generate a source IP address. My question is, is it possible to specify the source IP using scapy, even if that address is a real address being used on the network.

I basically want to simulate an attack that looks like it is coming from another device on the network.

Comment: Scapy can do almost anything you want.

Comment: ok great I hadn't seen any examples of specifying the source IP, but if it can do it, then fantastic !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scapy_pkt = Ether(dst='00:00:0c:01:01:14', src='00:00:0c:01:01:13')/ \
            IP(dst='1.1.1.14', src='1.1.1.13')/ \
            TCP(sport=1025, dport=80, \
                flags='S', seq=99999)
```

Comment: perfect many thanks that was exactly what I was looking for